# jQuery clone() tr issue - input text value stays empty

Tags: jquery

I've been struggelig for a while with the clone function of jquery. I have a table and on the right side + and - buttons to add or delete a row.

Here's the code I'm using, 
basically: clone the closest row you can find and and add it inbetween the current and next row.

```
  $('.btn-addTableRow').click(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('.tablerow');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
  });
```

As for the row itself I have 4 columns

```
    Date   | time from | time to | +/-
 Mo, 14.01 |  __:__    |  __:__  | +/-
 Di, 15.01 |  __:__    |  __:__  | +/-
```

the input fields for the time values are text fields with a placeholder in them. When cloning the table row they are cloned as well. The date field on the other hand, the date is set with value="__". When cloning the table, the input get's cloned as well. in the source code, the date is still in the value but it doesn't get displayed.

Would love to get a hit. thanks for your time!

Comment: that's what clone actually does, it copies only the HTML, for the value attribute you need to copy it manually using val function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm sorry, I was blind already. 
this caused the problem:

```
$clone.find(':text').val('');
```